# Does Israel have a contracted minimum quota of people they must inject with Pfizer vaccines?

Tags: covid-19, vaccines, israel

From [Outcry to the world, from Israel!!! (NL+ENG subtitles)](https://youtu.be/WMsn0bj_P6o?t=791) (transcript from [The Current Situation in Israel as Told by Ilana Rachel Daniel](https://www.weblyf.com/2021/03/the-current-situation-in-israel-as-told-by-ilana-rachel-daniel/))

> “There is a contract. There is an actual physical contract between Pfizer and our government. We’ve seen only a redacted version. What we know is that there is a penalty clause. They must. Right now the government of Israel is acting incredibly desperately because they have some sort of quota of people they must reach, that they must inject. I don’t know what this penalty clause entails. Obviously, it must be something more terrible than risking health of generation and the generations to come of your entire people, but we know that that exists and we know that they are in a situation where they feel a lot of pressure and so they’re acting foolishly and more and more extremely. They are sending out messages offering people a slice of pizza to get their injection. It’s just a twilight zone!”

Is there a contracted minimum quota of individuals that the Israeli government must vaccinate?

Comment: It would seem more likely there is a minimum amount of vaccine they must *buy*. What the penalty clause states isn't known by the author, who is using it as an 'appeal to emotion' argument, and says the published contract is a fake.

Comment: Surely the Israeli government would want to vaccinate as many people as possible, quota or no quota?

Comment: For reference, the redacted version of that contract seems to be this one: https://govextra.gov.il/media/30806/11221-moh-pfizer-collaboration-agreement-redacted.pdf I wonder how we could answer this, if the full agreement is secret, only redacted version available (perhaps there is even a full nother protocol ;). Unless there are leaks. So: how do 'they know'? I really hope that any answer will stick to such facts and refrain from speculations. Absent such leaks or FOIA, this might not be answered for quite some time?

Comment: Also: This quota even is mentioned in the International Criminal Court complaint https://cdn.exiteme.com/exitetogo/www.makorona.com/userfiles/files/investigation-Pfizer.pdf (p22) Meaning a proper law firm also believes that, and Den Hague accepted it for now prima facie (still no true/false verdict, but certainly for notability)

Comment: @LangLаngС If I understand you link correctly this is a letter/ request someone send to the ICC. It doesn't imply anything whatsoever about what the ICC thinks about the situation.

Comment: @quarague The ICC in The Hague just has this on the table https://israel-news.co.il/archives/24845 , not any verdict drawn whatsoever. It's just quite notable, for the question, not (hardly) advancing any answer… https://www.allisrael.com/israeli-group-claims-government-is-guilty-of-violating-nuremberg-code-crimes-against-humanity-in-vaccination-campaign So, really ["accepted"](https://www.allisrael.com/israeli-group-claims-government-is-guilty-of-violating-nuremberg-code-crimes-against-humanity-in-vaccination-campaign) might be between premature wording/hyperbole/lost in translation?

Comment: On page 4 of the [link](https://cdn.exiteme.com/exitetogo/www.makorona.com/userfiles/files/investigation-Pfizer.pdf) from @LangLаngС section "Rule of the Wise" uses examples of the *rule of two*, but the redundancy of having two of something is quite different from the need for two keys to arm a warhead as stated. It further claims that this philosophy is *pioneered* by Israel, but since redundancy techniques have been in use since before the State of Israel existed, I stopped reading what seems to be romantic nonsense. A law firm should stick to law.

Comment: @WeatherVane Be that as you wish. The point important here is on p22: the claim to be investigated posted by Andrew is not just a fringe person shouting on asocial media, but a very widespread belief. Currently, I see a YouTube link, and I have low motivation to watch it, wonder how much have seen it *&* believe it. If Andrew chooses to include that link, (or others) no further doubts over notability should arise.

Comment: @LangLаngС I see, the claim on page 22 is that the people of Israeli are to be guinea-pigs ("goal on experimentation"), and that is under a secret deal with the supplier which has not been published. Presumably if that is the case, people will be given different dosages, or a different number of doses. But surely that's already been done, for the vaccine to have been given a certificate? And anyway, OP's linked story says "the health ministry is not monitoring the after-effects of their vaccination program".

Comment: @WeatherVane Well. It says what is the claim here: "Section4: The quota at all costs". The guinea pig in human experiment angle seems not to be in question at all, as per gov-doc on sharing all 'experimental data', and the CEO himself: [Jerusalem post: "Pfizer CEO Albert Bourla calls Israel 'world's lab' in interview to NBC"](https://www.jpost.com/breaking-news/pfizer-ceo-albert-bourla-calls-israel-worlds-lab-in-interview-to-nbc-660349). (&no, as anywhere, Pfizer only has 'emergency use' in IL; Bibi doing TV-ads claiming the FDA(!) would have issued proper license; testing is nowhere complete)

Comment: Note that the claim also indirectly amounts to the German(!) firm BioNTec forcing medical experimentation on Israel(!) population?!

Comment: @WeatherVane If you had continued reading, you might have learnt that the WHO is nonchalantly described as non-independent (p. 13) and that some billionaires have their own agenda in this context (p.25)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen do you mean p25 *"vii. involvment of nonscientic and non-medical billionaires philanthropists, uncovering their true ideology and objectives"* ? They seems to be taking a swipe at anyone they don't like. Can't a philanthropist donate unless they are an expert in that field? The word **polemic** comes to mind.

Comment: @Hagen nice catch, but Ilana had pretty much Godwin’d the topic already.

Comment: The only interesting redaction seems to be at the start of section 3.  The rest is largely of names, dates, indemnification of damages, dispute resolution and data ownership. The section 3 redaction is far smaller than the space a commercial specification of how many doses would be delivered when would take up.  The high Israeli vaccination seems to have been caused by a combination of the availability of vaccine, the high number of positive cases (per population 6th highest in the world) and a general election. The answer to the original question seems to be "no"

Comment: [A recent vid on the situation](https://youtu.be/bFB2AA28_q4?t=5910) (interesting even vefore that —esp for this Q: no updates, but even kickbacks for Bibi mentioned , but most relevant timecode added) + [of course Gal Gur](https://twitter.com/GalGur_/status/1387377770137858057)